# Alt condition not working for choropleth missing values N.A

Tags: python-3.x, vega, altair, vega-lite

I am plotting a choropleth where I am using the color scheme "blues" 
I want a default color for counties where I don't have any data i.e. N.A. 
The default color has hex-code: #dbe9f6 
I am using alt condition for this but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
from altair import Scale,Color

fg = alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(
stroke='black',
strokeWidth=0.05
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf1, 'fips', ['Pill_per_pop'])
).encode(
    color = alt.condition('datum.Pill_per_pop!==null',Color('Pill_per_pop:Q',scale=Scale(scheme='blues')),alt.value('#dbe9f6'))
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)
```

My output is :
[image: Generated Output]

Expected output is :
[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it seems like the null values are breaking the conditional encoding. I was able to get it working by using a calculate transform to turn nulls into negative numbers, and then conditioning on this instead:

```
alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='black',
    strokeWidth=0.05
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf1, 'fips', ['Pill_per_pop'])
).transform_calculate(
    Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
).encode(
    color = alt.condition(
        'datum.Pill_per_pop > 0',
        alt.Color('Pill_per_pop:Q', scale=Scale(scheme='blues')),
        alt.value('#dbe9f6')
    )
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
)
```

Comment: This is off-topic but your help would be greatly appreciated for this question of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224026/how-to-add-a-slider-to-a-choropleth-in-altair