# How to add a slider to a choropleth in altair?

Tags: python-3.x, vega, altair, vega-lite

I am trying to add a slider to my choropleth plot. 
The slider is based on "years" from 2006 to 2012 
My data is like this: 
[image: data]

It can be downloaded from here:
[sample_data.csv](https://github.com/sdasara95/Opioid-Crisis)

When I plot the county level choropleth, It is doing an inner join w.r.t fips code for county using transform_lookup 
This is my code:

```
slider = alt.binding_range(min=2006, max=2012, step=1)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2006})

alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='black',
    strokeWidth=0.05
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', ['Pill_per_pop','year'])
).transform_calculate(
    Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
).encode(
    color = alt.condition(
        'datum.Pill_per_pop > 0',
        alt.Color('Pill_per_pop:Q', scale=Scale(scheme='blues')),
        alt.value('#dbe9f6')
    )).add_selection(
    select_year
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
).transform_filter(
    select_year
)
```

This code is giving me a choropleth plot with a slider but the plots are wrong. 
I feel that it is taking the first occurence for fips code and is not filtering based on the year. 
I feel this is because of the transform_lookup method mapping the county ids to fips code.
This is the output:
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the lookup transform only finds the first matching index - it's a one-sided join, not a multi-join. If you want to join multiple data entries per key, you'll have to use a dataset with multiple columns.

For your data, you can produce such a dataset using the pandas [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method, and then within Altair you can undo this operation after the lookup by using the [fold transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html#fold-transform)

For your data it might look something like this:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

us_counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
fdf = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdasara95/Opioid-Crisis/master/sample_data.csv')
fdf['year'] = fdf['year'].astype(str)
fdf = fdf.pivot(index='fips', columns='year', values='Pill_per_pop').reset_index()
columns = [str(year) for year in range(2006, 2013)]

slider = alt.binding_range(min=2006, max=2012, step=1)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2006})

alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='black',
    strokeWidth=0.05
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', columns)
).transform_fold(
    columns, as_=['year', 'Pill_per_pop']
).transform_calculate(
    year='parseInt(datum.year)',
    Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
).encode(
    color = alt.condition(
        'datum.Pill_per_pop > 0',
        alt.Color('Pill_per_pop:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues')),
        alt.value('#dbe9f6')
    )).add_selection(
    select_year
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
).transform_filter(
    select_year
)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using your approach but I am unable to do it. 
I have shared the data as requested.

Comment: Updated the answer with data - the issue was I'd assumed the year column was strings.