# Adding dynamic tooltip and title to Choropleth (with slider) in Altair

Tags: python, altair, choropleth

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59227589/4687531), @jakevdp produced the very nice choropleth in
Altair using a slider (pasted below for convenience):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

us_counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
fdf = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdasara95/Opioid-Crisis/master/sample_data.csv')
fdf['year'] = fdf['year'].astype(str)
fdf = fdf.pivot(index='fips', columns='year', values='Pill_per_pop').reset_index()
columns = [str(year) for year in range(2006, 2013)]

slider = alt.binding_range(min=2006, max=2012, step=1)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2006})

alt.Chart(us_counties).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='black',
    strokeWidth=0.05
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', columns)
).transform_fold(
    columns, as_=['year', 'Pill_per_pop']
).transform_calculate(
    year='parseInt(datum.year)',
    Pill_per_pop='isValid(datum.Pill_per_pop) ? datum.Pill_per_pop : -1'  
).encode(
    color = alt.condition(
        'datum.Pill_per_pop > 0',
        alt.Color('Pill_per_pop:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues')),
        alt.value('#dbe9f6')
    )).add_selection(
    select_year
).properties(
    width=700,
    height=400
).transform_filter(
    select_year
)
```

I'm new to Altair, and wanted to understand how to make a few modifications
to this plot:

1. How can we add a title to this plot that varies with the slider value
   i.e. "Number of Pills in year {slider_value_here}"?
2. How can we change the slider label to be customized to `yr` rather than the current `year_year` value?
3. How can we add a hover tooltip to each county i.e. fips value, with the following
   values, {year: {slider_year_value}, fips: {fips_code_value_on_hover}, number_pills: {Pill_per_pop}}?
4. How can we add an animation widget to this slider e.g. have a play button that automatically varies the slider value (where the timing can be controlled in the code)?

Any help with the modifications to this code would be extremely helpful. I did try
inserting `tooltip` in various places to make query 3 work, but couldn't make it
happen.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for including a clear and reproducible example! Just a heads up for the future that it can be a good idea to break your bullet points into separate question so that it is easier for others to find them when searching. I don't believe everything you want is achievable in Altair/Vegalite currently, but here is my best attempt at answering:

1. > How can we add a title to this plot that varies with the slider value i.e. "Number of Pills in year {slider_value_here}"?

   I found [this comment mentioning that this is not possible for axis titles](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2011#issuecomment-597781332), so I would believe it is not possible for chart titles either (not sure though). An alternative approach would be to insert a small chart instead of a title and use `mark_text` to update the year, [similar to this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71210072/can-i-turn-altair-axis-titles-into-links/71210807#71210807)
2. > How can we change the slider label to be customized to yr rather than the current year_year value?

   Set the name parameter in the `binding_range` *instead* of the `selection_single`, e.g. `slider = alt.binding_range(name='yr ', min=2006, max=2012, step=1)` (extra space for not having the slider right next to the name.
3. > How can we add a hover tooltip to each county i.e. fips value, with the following values, {year: {slider_year_value}, fips: {fips_code_value_on_hover}, number_pills: {Pill_per_pop}}?

   First change the lookup to also fetch the fips column:

   ```
    from_=alt.LookupData(fdf, 'fips', columns + ['fips'])
   ```

   Then pass a list to tooltip indicating the column types since they come from the lookup and are not in in the main dataframe you passed to the chart.

   ```
    tooltip=['year:O', 'fips:Q', 'Pill_per_pop:Q']
   ```
4. > How can we add an animation widget to this slider e.g. have a play button that automatically varies the slider value (where the timing can be controlled in the code)?

   [Animations are not yet supported in vegalite](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4060)