# Can I turn altair axis titles into links?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

In altair, possible to turn the axis titles into links?

(I understand how to use [href](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Href.html) for points, but not sure if I can do something similar for axis labels.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to format axis title like that and don't see any property in [the Vega-Lite docs](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#title) that suggest you can. However, you could place a text mark strategically to receive the same result:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()
chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_circle().encode(
        x=alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon', title=''),
        y='Weight_in_lbs',
        color='Origin'
)

text = alt.Chart().mark_text(
    align="center",
    baseline="top",
    fontSize=11,
    fontWeight=600,
    color='#007bff',
    href='https://stackoverflow.com'
).encode(
    x=alt.value(200),  # pixels from left
    y=alt.value(322),  # pixels from top
    text=alt.value("Miles_per_Gallon")
)

text + chart
```

[image]